# Vertical scrolling website with variable text. How?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm trying to build a website with vertical slides, but I've run into a problem. The first slide is 100% x 100%, so that's not a problem, but the following slides has a variable amount of text on them in a DIV - sometimes not enough to fill out the full height of the slide.

- When the text is higher than the browser window, I want the slide-DIV to expand with it.
- When the text is too short to fill it out, I want the slide-DIV to stay 100% high.

Here is a [draft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZh93.jpg).

Can you help me with the CSS for the DIVs? Thank you.

Comment: Just set a min-height.

Comment: have you tried to set min-height: 100% to your div?

Answer (score 0):

try to give

```
min-height: 100px;
max-height: 1155px;
```

then the window will expand when text exceeded 100px

Comment: it is to just set max height.i particularly used 1155 as i have used it in my project.